Is the semicolon now optional in bash conditionals with [[ .. ]] in version 5.2?
The following bash script:
#!/bin/bash

TEST_VAR=""

if [[ -z $TEST_VAR ]] then
    echo "empty"
else
    echo "$TEST_VAR"
fi

despite missing a semicolon before "then", does not throw an error in bash 5.2 and completes successfully, even returning 0.
Running the above script on a system running bash 5.1 or 5.0 fails as expected.
Why is this? Did bash change their parser in version 5.2? After searching I can't find any reference to this change. Did bash intentionally change behavior here, or is this a bug?

The change was suggested here https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00140.html I said it'd confuse the average user here https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00143.html but no one else opposed and it landed in 5.2. So it's not a bug

Thanks to oguz ismail, who provided proofs to back up my intuition that I wasn't able to find - both the relevant mailing list discussion and the git commit that implemented this.

In a nutshell, following a mailing list discussion happened before the release of 5.2, it had been found that the behavior of [[]] requiring a semicolon at the end was inconsistent with that of other compound commands, which didn't require a semicolon at the end, and [[]]'s behavior was changed to conform to those before 5.2 rolled out.

]] is a reserved word:
$ LANG=C type ]]
]] is a shell keyword

From Reserved Words (Bash Reference Manual) - emphasys mine:

Reserved words are words that have special meaning to the shell. They are used to begin and end the shell’s compound commands.

And [[ expression ]] is, in fact, a compound command.
Historically, other compound commands such as {} or () never required a semicolon after them:
$ if { true; } then echo foo; fi # no semicolon after the first `}`, no syntax error
foo
$ if ( true ) then echo foo; fi # no semicolon after the first `)`, no syntax error
foo
$ if { true; } then { echo foo; } fi # no semicolon after the second `}`, no syntax error either
foo

So [[]]'s behavior was changed to conform to those before 5.2 rolled out.

I'm not sure if this answer is correct, but even if it is, it's surely incomplete; consider something like [[ "$foo" ]] && [[ "$bar" ]], which is valid, even though [[ "$foo" ]]; && [[ "$bar" ]] is not valid.

@ruakh What I initially wrote fits the documentation. && is not a reserved word, so my initial reasoning, which addressed reserved words specifically, didn't mean to address &&, so that itself doesn't make it wrong. However it was wrong for other reasons, and I've changed it to something else that, while researching this, I found more convincing. Which unfortunatley makes the answer now just complete speculation.

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?h=devel&id=a7309caba40ca85748b1bcbe38dbaa88c5d9e0dc

@oguzismail That's the smoking gun, thanks a lot for finding that. This was just speculation, I only correctly guessed that it was changed because "it makes sense", do you mind posting an answer?

It wouldn't be any different than this answer.

Great reasoning "# allow reserved words after a conditional command just because" (bottom of file in link if curious)

@oguzismail Ok I updated my answer including links to the discussion and to the commit then. Thanks again

@DavidC.Rankin It makes sense if you really think about it. No semicolon is required between ), }, done, esac, fi and ), }, do, done, elif, else, esac, fi, then (for x do case x in esac done is a valid command for example, no semicolons needed), it's been this way forever and POSIX mandates it. So why not add ]] and )) to that list?

Oh, I get it, I just hear Linus' harping about eliminating passive-voice and ensuring every commit and comment explains clearly why something was done. I don't think "just because" would fly :) Looks like ShellCheck hasn't got the memo. Try if [ "$#" -gt 2 ] then printf "I have %s\n" "$#"; fi :(

@DavidC.Rankin Well Bash is a GNU project, so whatever Linus thinks doesn't really matter

well, that linked-to post from Koichi Murase says that other shells accept that construct, and I suppose that's also an ok reason to accept it in Bash too. Of course it can never work with [ ... ], so there's still some confusion to be had for those of us who have managed to avoid getting too deep into the shell language quirks :)

as an aside, got to love Chet's comment there within the thread: "If I get interested in something, and I have the time, I'll work on it even
if there's no practical benefit."
